# continue loop if arrow keys are not pressed in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying create this function such that if any key besides any of the arrow keys are pressed, the loop continues until an arrow key is pressed.  The program crashes every time and doesn't display the error.  Any idea why?

```
def speed(self, key):
    # Figure out if it was an arrow key. If so
    # adjust speed

    n = 'go'
    while n == 'go':
        if key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_speed=-5
            y_speed=0
            return x_speed, y_speed
            n = 'stop'
        if key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_speed = 5
            y_speed = 0
            return x_speed, y_speed
            n = 'stop'
        if key == pygame.K_UP:
            y_speed = -5
            x_speed = 0
            return x_speed, y_speed
            n = 'stop'
        if key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            y_speed = 5
            x_speed = 0
            return x_speed, y_speed
            n = 'stop'
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: That function will loop infinitely unless called with an arrow key. Ie. it will not crash, but it won't return either. Also your n = 'stop' statements will never execute since they are immediatly after the return. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Gustave Giráldez:  Okay, basically I just don't want the program to crash when the user presses a non-arrow key.  What's the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observing the following criteria:

- The loop will only end when `key` is an arrow, because the only `return` statements and `n = 'stop'` statements happen when `key` is an arrow key.
- The value of `key` will never change from inside the loop, because the only declaration of `key` is in the definition of `speed()`

We determine: if we call speed() with a non-arrow `key`, the loop will never finish. When you hit an infinite loop in the main execution thread of a program, it has a habit of freezing everything and eating delicious CPU cycles.

The solution is to implement your logic asynchronously. If you press a key, it should observe the state of the system, change whatever it needs to trigger actions, then quickly return so as to not slow the program. A never-ending `while` loop isn't anything close to optimal in the middle of your key-detection logic.

Answer (score 5):

I have never used pygame in my life, nor written a single word of python, but here's my guess:

```
def speed(self, key):
    # Figure out if it was an arrow key. If so
    # adjust speed
    if key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        x_speed=-5
        y_speed=0
        return x_speed, y_speed

    if key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        x_speed = 5
        y_speed = 0
        return x_speed, y_speed

    if key == pygame.K_UP:
        y_speed = -5
        x_speed = 0
        return x_speed, y_speed

    if key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        y_speed = 5
        x_speed = 0
        return x_speed, y_speed
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because when an arrow key isn't pressed you are effectively doing this:

```
n = "go"
while n == "go":
    continue
```

Apologies for syntax errors, and also if I'm wrong, ell.

Comment: that's exactly what's happening.